# Longest Chord in a circle?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, power-of-the-point

A rectangle with side lengths $AB = 3$ and $BC = 11$ is inscribed within a circle, as shown. There are two chords $\overline{AS}$ of the circle which are bisected by segment $\overline{BC}$. Find the length of the longer such chord.

[image]

Comment: The longest Chord is'nt the diameter?

Comment: Hint. Can you show angle $MSC$ is a right angle?

Comment: Where do you see a second chord? I got $\frac{139}{\sqrt{157}}.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Let $S$ move from $B$ to $C$ on the upper side, and $M$ be the intersection of $BC$ with $AS$. At $S=B$, $SM/MA=0$, after that $SM/MA$ increases, gets to a maximum, then decreases such as at $S=C$ the ratio is $0$ once again. As long as $AM=AS$ is attained once, and it is not the maximum, then it is attained twice.

Comment: @Andrei $M$ is a mid-point of $BC$. See please better the given.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think it's given that $M$ is the middle of $AS$, not of $BC$. It does not say that $AS$ bisects $BC$

Comment: Oh yes. I still don't know English. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $BM = x$. Then $AM^2 = 9 + x^2$ (Pythagoras) and if $M$ bisects $AS$ then also $AM^2 = x(11 - x)$ (intersecting chords). Hence $(x - 1)(2x - 9) = 0$, giving $AS = 2\sqrt10$ or $3\sqrt13$.

Answer (score 0):

we can calculate the length of $ \overline{AM} $ by using the Pytagoras Theorm ( $\overline{AB}^2+\overline{BM}^2=\overline{AM}^2$ ) 
Lastly, calculate $\overline{MS}$ by $\overline{MS} \  \overline{AM}=\overline{BM}\overline{MC}$

then you know which is bigger and how long it is.